# Are there any documented example usages of film (ie, film film, not video or digital) for in-flight entertainment?

Tags: airliner, aviation-history, inflight-entertainment

Regarding this excellent question: [What was the inflight entertainment in the early seventies?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/what-was-the-inflight-entertainment-in-the-early-seventies)

There's a mention that the "TRANSCOM 8mm film cassette" (that was film-film, ie the plastic stuff you can see-through, not video tape) was used on some planes.

I've found all the references to this on the WWW **are poor references copying each other** with no details (but I may be missing something).

1. Can anyone find literally an image of film-projector technology being used for in-flight entertainment?
2. Are there any specific references / image examples to the "TRANSCOM 8mm film cassette"
3. What year was about the last year film projection technology was used (if it was ever used?)

Or indeed -- memories of these things, even better! Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know film projectors were definitely used on early 747s - converting part of the passenger area into a theater is part of the design. I was able to dig up the photo below showing the projector mechanism, which is pretty impressive to look at.

[image: 747 Film Projector (Screencap)]

I'm not sure whose system that is, but it looks like a 35mm projector so it probably predates the TRANSCOM cassettes.

Can't help you with #2 or #3 though.

Comment: incredible find!  wow!  thanks...

Comment: The video link is dead. Can you dig again? :)

Comment: @Farhan Unfortunately that was the only source for the movie I knew of (that's why I grabbed the screen capture, I was afraid it might go dead on us one day).  I'm not sure if it's just "unavailable" for maintenance or if it's actually gone dead for good, so I'll leave the link for now in the hope that it comes back. If it's still dead in a week or two I'll adjust the answer to just reference the photo. (Stupid link rot!)